# Speed up looping code for coordinate conversion

Tags: r, loops, coordinates

I have a data set of tree stems and their position, originally in plot-coordinates. I need to convert these coordinates to utm coordinates. I have written the following functions to convert our plot coordinates to utm coordinates and the following script to run this over the entire dataset. The problem I've encountered is that I have 261403 stems total, and the script has been taking an incredibly long time to run. I know that loops are in general slow and should be avoided. Any advice on how to perform this without using a loop?

Defining the functions:

```
    newcoords_x=function(gx,gy)
    {  
      rot_x <- gx*cos(-0.031989084) - gy*sin(-0.031989084)
      rot_y<- gx*sin(-0.031989084) + gy*cos(-0.031989084) 
      utm_x<-rot_x+625774
      utm_y<-rot_y+1011776  
      return(utm_x)
    }

    newcoords_y=function(gx,gy)
    { 
      rot_x <- gx*cos(-0.031989084) - gy*sin(-0.031989084)
      rot_y<- gx*sin(-0.031989084) + gy*cos(-0.031989084)  
      utm_x<-rot_x+625774
      utm_y<-rot_y+1011776
      return(utm_y)
    }
```

The loop:

```
    for (i in 1:length(x$tag))
    {
      x$utm_x[i]=newcoords_x(x$gx[i], x$gy[i])
      x$utm_y[i]<-newcoords_y(x$gx[i], x$gy[i])
    }
```

Here is some sample data, x,

```
    tag    gx    gy 
    2  994.1 488.3 
    4  990.5 488.9   
    6  993.5 498.3  
    7  992.7 469.3 
    8  981.9 473.5 
    13 983.0 452.6
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing is to vectorize operations instead of using loop. You can do:

```
transform(x, utm_x=gx*cos(-0.031989084) - gy*sin(-0.031989084) + 625774
           , utm_y=gx*sin(-0.031989084) + gy*cos(-0.031989084) + 1011776)

#  tag    gx    gy    utm_x   utm_y
#1   2 994.1 488.3 626783.2 1012232
#2   4 990.5 488.9 626779.6 1012233
#3   6 993.5 498.3 626782.9 1012242
#4   7 992.7 469.3 626781.2 1012213
#5   8 981.9 473.5 626770.5 1012218
#6  13 983.0 452.6 626771.0 1012197
```